# Using form_end in Symfony causes Internal server error

Tags: php, symfony, twig, xdebug, symfony-forms

I recently cleaned my Twig templates in order to avoid deprecated calls on Symfony 2.8 and I got a strange behaviour.

This is how my template looks like :

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form_template'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

This is how my form looks like :

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', 'text', array('label' => 'your email'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'some_fancy_name';
    }
}
```

And this is how my controller looks like

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), null);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') 
    {
        // do something with the form contents
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('somewhere'));
    }
    return $this->render('::myform.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

When rendering the template, everything is working fine until Twig renders the `form_end()` function and then throws an `Error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! (500 Internal Server Error)`

I tried increasing the `xdebug.max_nesting_level` setting in my PHP configuration but it did not help, the only fix that I found which resolves the issue is :

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form_template'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
</form>
```

Which is an ugly fix.

Now I am wondering why am I getting such error with `form_end(form)` while everything works fine with `form_rest(form)` ?

Comment: can't you get a more detailled error message ?

Comment: There's a note in the [documentation on embedded form collections](http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) that specifically mentions that message. (I can't link directly to it, but just search for the message on that page.)

Comment: @t-n-y I have one but it's long and painful
@Don'tPanic yes I've been to this page but the only thing they encourage is increasing the `xdebug.max_nesting_level`

Comment: how do you want us to help you if you don't show all the info, because you think taht this is "long and painful" ...

Comment: @t-n-y you asked for it, so [here it is](https://files.gogaz.org/stacktrace.txt), but it's around 3MB of pure stack trace

Comment: Well, if you are using nested form collections, they do offer another alternative to increasing that setting. _"... or render each form field by hand using `form_row`"_

Comment: @Don'tPanic I tried with form_row instead of form_widget but I don't see any change !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `form_widget(form)` renders the whole form recursively as indicated in the [documentation on form collections](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and causes the serveur to exceed maximum nesting level. Rendering every field manually fixed the issue.

Moreover, calling `form_end(form)` calls `form_rest(form)`, so when this is not necessary, I had to manually disable the rest rendering to fully work this out, according to [documentation on form functions and variables](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables).

I had to change my Twig template to the following:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form_template'} }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```